# How to test Function passed as an argument in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mocking

How to test Function passed as an argument in Flutter?

code:

```
Future<User> execute({
    required String username,
    required String password,
    required void Function(AuthFailure fail) onFailure,
    required void Function(User user) onSuccess,
}) async {
    if (username.isNonValid || password.isNonValid) {
      onFailure(const AuthFailure.wrongCredentials()); // I want to test this line
      return const User.anonymous();
    }
    ...
}
```

test:

```
  test('use case - failure execution for incorrect credentials', () async {
    // GIVEN
    // WHEN
    final user = await useCase.execute(
      username: "noname",
      password: "password",
      onFailure: (fail) {},
      onSuccess: (user) {},
    );
    // THEN
    // TODO how to verify onFailure call inside useCase?
    expect(user, const User.anonymous());
  });
```

Or maybe testing this way is not the idiomatic way, because the test becomes more white-box instead black-box? Should I perceive passing functions as arguments to use cases as anti-pattern? I can change it then. The proposition is to return sth like `Either` from `useCase.execute()`:

```
Future<Either<Failure, Success>> execute({
    required String username,
    required String password,
}) async {
    if (username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {
      // return wrapper around AuthFailure.wrongCredentials()) of Either left subtype (Either has two subtypes)
    }
    ...
}
```

This way I only verify return type, and all the lines are covered this way. It's gonna work, but I feel better with the simplest, not the smartest solution.

PS I use Mocktail for mocking, but using Mockito in solution is also warmly welcomed.

Comment: Why can't you have your `onFail` callback set a flag and later test that the flag is set?

Comment: @jamesdlin because it's quite ugly IMO. I strive for minimal complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to verify that the callback is triggered, I personally would just make your callback set a flag and then test that flag afterward, which I think is straightforward, simple, and easy to understand with no magic:

```dart
test('use case - failure execution for incorrect credentials', () async {
  var failureCalled = false;

  final user = await useCase.execute(
    username: "noname",
    password: "password",
    onFailure: (fail) => failureCalled = true,
    onSuccess: (user) {},
  );

  expect(user, const User.anonymous());
  expect(failureCalled, true);
});
```

But if you really want to use `Mock`s, you will need some `Mock` object to use and to call instance methods on that in callbacks.  With Mockito you could do:

```dart
test('use case - failure execution for incorrect credentials', () async {
  dynamic mock = Mock();

  final user = await useCase.execute(
    username: "noname",
    password: "password",
    onFailure: (fail) => mock.fail(fail),
    onSuccess: (user) {},
  );

  expect(user, const User.anonymous());
  verify(mock.fail(any)).called(1);
});
```

Some things to note:

- To avoid declaring a class with the expected instance methods and then code-generating stubs, create a raw `Mock` instance but declare it as `dynamic` to disable static type-checking.  This will then take advantage the [`Mock.noSuchMethod`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/Mock/noSuchMethod.html) implementation.
- You can't use `onFailure: mock.fail` directly since the `Mock` has no generated stubs, and `mock.fail` will just be `null` instead of a `Function`.

I am not experienced with Mocktail, but I imagine that you could do something similar.

Comment: Ahh you meant using flag in tests - that's totally fine, and works like a charm! In a meantime I realised I don't really want such a detailed tests, and it will be just testing output ATM :) Now I clearly see how `Either` approach makes tests simpler and holistic.